# Multiple database switching dynamic in node-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

i have searched lot to get a solution to my problem. but didn't got it.
if anyone have the experience in such situations please help me.

i have created a application server in node express with MySQL a database.
and successfully create REST API endpoints which works successfully.

but our projects scaled up. a new client approaches so we need to serve those clients too.
those client may have 1k users.but the database schema is same.

solution 1: create a separate server and database for each client with different port no.
but i don't think this is good solution because if we have 100 client we can't maintain the code base.

solution 2: create a separate database for each client and switch database connection at run time. 
but i don't understand how to implement solution 2.  any suggestion highly appreciated.

if more than one client requesting same server how to know which database need to connect using the endpoint URL. i there any alternate way to tackle this situation.

my solution: create a middle ware to find out the which database is required and return the connection string.is it good idea.

middleware. in below example i use JWT token which contain database name.

```
const dbHelper=new db();
class DbChooser {
constructor(){
    this. db=
        {
            wesa:{
                host: "xxx",
                user: "xxxx",
                password: "xxxxx",
                database: "hdgh",
                connectionLimit:10,
                connectTimeout:30000,
                multipleStatements:true,
                charset:"utf8mb4"
            },
            svn:{
                host: "x.x.x.x.",
                user: "xxxx",
                password: "xxx",
                database: "xxx",
                connectionLimit:10,
                connectTimeout:30000,
                multipleStatements:true,
                charset:"utf8mb4"
            }

        };
}

async getConnectiontring(req,res,next){
    //console.log(req.decoded);
    let d=new DbChooser();
    let con=d.db[req.decoded.userId];
    console.log(mysql.createPool(con));
    next();
}
}
module.exports=DbChooser;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a config JSON. On every request, request header should have a client_id based on the client_id we can get the instance of the database connection.

your db config JSON

```
var dbconfig = {
          'client1': {
            databasename: '',
            host: '',
            password: '',
            username: ''
          },
          'client2': {
            databasename: '',
            host: '',
            password: '',
            username: ''
          }
        }
```

You should declare a global object, to maintain the singleton db instances for every client.

```
global.dbinstances = {};
```

on every request, you are going to check whether the instance is already available in your global object or not. If it's available you can go continue to the next process, otherwise it creates a new instance.

```
app.use('*', function(req,res) {
   let client_id = req.headers.client_id;
   if(global.instance[client_id]) {
     next();
   } else {
     const config = dbconfig[client_id];
     connectoDb(config, client_id);
   }

}

 function connectoDb(config, client_id) {
      //.. once it is connected

      global.instance.push({client_id: con}); //con refers to the db connection instance.
 }
```

Comment: but how to know which database i need to  connect by using request.  all client have same end point too. how can i map client id and database. in above example for every HTTP route i need to get connection string at first. Violette DRY

Comment: You can create a singleton instance.

Comment: could you please help the step to follow

Comment: Thanks. Another this is that how to know which data base is need to connect. If I pass some unique I'd from client side which vulnerable to the attack as you know. What is the best method

Comment: encrypt the client_id with some salt value, and decrypt it in the server side, so it adds extra protection to the app.

Comment: So no need to use redis . And how to access data from or con object from Singleton instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189163/discussion-between-sreejith-sreeji-and-bear-nithi).

Comment: @Sreejithsreeji Did you get anywhere with this? I have a similar need to direct my REST API user's to a different db dependent upon argument(s) set/provided in their client apps.